# How to create subplots with seaborn? I am not achieving my expected result

Tags: seaborn, subplot

I am trying to create a simple subplot in seaborn using 1 row 2 columns. But am not getting the expected result. Instead my figures are displaying separately. Please help.

```
df = sns.load_dataset("tips")
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 2, figsize = (15,6))
sns.relplot(x = "tip", y= "total_bill" , data = df , hue = "smoker", kind = "line", 
        hue_order = ["No", "Yes"], ax = axes[0])
sns.catplot(x = "tip", data = df, kind = "point", ax = axes[1])
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vfaR.png)

Answer (score 1):

Both the plots you are using - `relplot` and `catplot` are figure level plots. They cannot be used as sub plots. That is the reason you are seeing the initial blank plots and then the individual `relplot` and `catplot`.

You need to use `lineplot` and `pointplot` respectively instead, which will allow you to use the subplots. Note that `kind='line'` is no longer required, so it has been commented out in the code below...

```
df = sns.load_dataset("tips")
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 2, figsize = (15,6))
sns.lineplot(x = "tip", y= "total_bill" , data = df , hue = "smoker", #kind = "line", 
        hue_order = ["No", "Yes"], ax = axes[0])
sns.pointplot(x = "tip", data = df, kind = "point", ax = axes[1])
```

**Plot**

[image]